# Dynamically move /div tag on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, html, mouseover

What I want is to have a page where part of the text is enclosed in a `<div>` tag with a particular attribute, like text color:

```
<div style="color:#00FF00"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div> consectetur adipisicing elit,
```

When the user mouses over the next word in the text, in this case 'consectetur', the `</div>` tag would move one place to the right, so that the content now looks like this:

```
<div style="color:#00FF00"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div> adipisicing elit,
```

Cannot figure out for the life of me how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, it looks like you would want to use `<span>` in this context instead of `<div>`. `<span>` is an inline element and will prevent you many formatting headaches with the code you have listed above.

Comment: @JMC Creative: Looks like I was composing my answer at the same time you were making your comment. Great minds ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've devised one way of doing it  - the code could probably be tidied up and shrunk, but it works.

The idea is you have two nested span tags - one for the styled text which has already been highlighted, and another to hold only the next word in the sequence for jQuery event binding.

Put whatever string you want in the _string variable and away you go.

```
<style type="text/css">
    html { font-size: 20pt; }
    .red { color: red; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var _highlightIndex = 0;
var _string = "Here is some test text to highlight";

$(document).ready(function()
{
    RenderSpan();
});

function BindEvents()
{
    $("#outer .nextword").mouseover(function()
    {
        RenderSpan();
    });
}

function RenderSpan()
{
    var array = _string.split(" ");
    // Use an array to store text to save repeated string concatenation
    var html = [];
    var i = 0;
    html[i++] = "<span class=\"red\">"
    // Add all elements that have already been turned red
    for (var j = 0; j < _highlightIndex; j++)
    {
        html[i++] = array[j];
        html[i++] = " ";
    }
    // Close the red span
    html[i++] = "</span>";
    // Add the next word in the sequence to its own span for the event to bind to
    html[i++] = "<span class=\"nextword\">";
    html[i++] = array[_highlightIndex];
    html[i++] = "</span>";
    html[i++] = " ";
    // Now add the remaining words with no span around them
    for (var k = _highlightIndex + 1; k < array.length; k++)
    {
        html[i++] = array[k];
        html[i++] = " ";
    }
    // Replace the html in the outer div
    $("#outer").html(html.join(""));
    // Increment the highlight index
    _highlightIndex++; // move this to the top of the function if you want to start with one red word
    // Re-bind the jQuery mouseover
    BindEvents();
}
</script>
<div id="outer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't use the `<div>` tag for that. Text is `display: inline` and the `<div>` is `display: block` so you're going to run into all kinds of issues just dealing with that.

What I would do, if I had this problem, would be to have each word enclosed in it's own `<span>` tag, so that your markup would look something like:

```
<p class="extendHilite">
  <span>Lorem </span><span>ipsum </span><span>dolor </span> <!-- and so on -->
</p>
```

Then use Javascript or jQuery to listen for the `onmouseover` event on all of the `<span>` elements within the paragraph. Your event handler will determine which span has been moused over and set the className of all prior spans to a style that gives the text a background color.

You can also do this with text ranges and absolute positioning, but that is a good deal harder.

Answer (score 1):

I think this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSVF4/1) does what you want.

It is pretty specific to your request (ie, assuming one div on the page and only the first word is mouseover-aware at a time), but I think you can use the idea to get what you are after. BTW, I use the same basic idea as the other folks, of wrapping the words after the div with span tags.

Answer (score 0):

As was commented on already, use the inline element `<span>` in this context, not `<div>`. This isn't a complete answer, but a contribution to a solution. It looks like you would need some javascript that would be able to recognize each word of a sentence.  This, in my mind, is the hard part.  Once you get that in place, it would be a simple matter of:

```
<span id="colored"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span> consectetur adipisicing elit, ...

$('.singleWord').hover(function(){
    var word = " " + $(this); // want a space before the word, right?
    $(this).remove();
    word.appendTo('span#colored');
});
```

Oh, yeah, I always forget to mention that this solution uses jQuery.  ;)